# После переустановки приложения) мне возвращаются все ,что я купил на место хотя я вернул товар так должно быть или нет!

Tags: java, android

Когда я возвращаю покупки в Android приложении(после переустановки приложения) мне возвращаются все ,что я купил  на место хотя я вернул товар так должно быть или нет!

!!!!! -Я  пробовал  сделать это на примере тестовой покупки !!!!!

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        mBillingClient();
    }

    private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();
    private String mSkuId1 = "mSkuId1";
    private String mSkuId2 = "mSkuId2";
    private BillingClient mBillingClient;

    public void mBillingClient() {
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
                if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                    //сюда мы попадем когда будет осуществлена покупка

                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();
                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete();
                        }

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete2();
                        }}

                }

            }
        }).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    //здесь мы можем запросить информацию о товарах и покупках
                    querySkuDetails();
                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId1, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete();
                        }

                        if(TextUtils.equals(mSkuId2, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete2();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //сюда мы попадем если что-то пойдет не так
            }
        });
    }



    private void querySkuDetails() {
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(mSkuId1);
        skuList.add(mSkuId2);
        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (responseCode == 0) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Start(View view) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId1))
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }

    public void Start2(View view) {
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(mSkuDetailsMap.get(mSkuId2))
                .build();
        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams);
    }


    public void payComplete() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean( "loadUr1" , true);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void payComplete2() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean( "loadUr2" , true);
        editor.apply();
    }


    private List<Purchase> queryPurchases() {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        return purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
    }

}
```

Comment: конечно должно, вы могли установить приложение на другом устройстве под ним аккаунтом, или удалить приложение а потом передумать и установить назад, это не значит. что вы вдруг лишились права на свои покупки и т.п.

Comment: Вы правильно поняли? (Я вернул товар  со своего аккаунта и получил средства назад) - почему я получаю вновь  товар за который я вернул деньги ?

Comment: Как проверить вернул ли пользователь товар?

Comment: Скорее всего это кэш маркета. Через какое-то время оно обновится и покупка исчезнет. Можно проверить это потерев все данные приложения маркета - покупка в приложении исчезнет. Чтобы программно получить свежие данные - надо специальный метод использовать. О нём в документации написано.